# How can I repair cracks at corners of tiled walls?

Tags: bathroom, silicone

[image]

I recently had a bathroom renovated these cracks are appearing in the corner of shower cubicle where two walls meet . Obviously workmanship not been good but is this easily fixed with a reliable long lasting result.

Thank you

Comment: The crack at the junction of the tiled walls is fairly common (though is easily prevented with framing techniques). The crack at the ceiling isn't at the actual corner. I'm not sure what we're seeing there.

Comment: not a big deal, just patch it up with new caulk.

Comment: With large tiles I like to use 1/4 round pieces. If you can't find a matching 1/4 round it could be a different color like a trim or accent strip.

Answer (score -1):

The area on top looks like it was sealed with white caulk.  You can re-seal this with white silicon caulk.  The other cracks look like it's grout.  Do you have any of the grout the contractor used?  IMHO, clean the old grout out and regrout. I've never had much luck getting new grout to stick to old.  You can also run caulk over it as well but this will show up.

Comment: Grout is rigid and does work well at corners or where the tile on the wall meets the top of a tub. I thought that the standard was to use silicone or other flexible caulk. However, I don't see how one could match the color of the grout.